# expand each unique combination with vector of dates

Tags: r

I have a data frame with unique combinations:

```
df <- data.frame(
    d = c("d1", "d2")
    , t = c("t1", "t2")
)
```

and a vector of dates:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2016/5/1"), as.Date("2016/7/1"), "months")
```

I would like to expand each row of the unique combinations to get this:

```
df1 <- expand.grid(d = c("d1"), t = c("t1"), date = dates)
df2 <- expand.grid(d = c("d2"), t = c("t2"), date = dates)
want <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

want data:

```
   d  t       date
1 d1 t1 2016-05-01
2 d1 t1 2016-06-01
3 d1 t1 2016-07-01
4 d2 t2 2016-05-01
5 d2 t2 2016-06-01
6 d2 t2 2016-07-01
```

Obviously this code works but I have many more unique combinations. I could use a loop but something similar to expand.grid, which does not work in this case, would be preferred:

```
combinations <- expand.grid(df, date = dates)
```

Is there an easy way to get "want" without resorting to a loop? Thanks.

Comment: `merge(df, dates)` does not produce what you want ? It just did in my console but maybe I misunderstood your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
tidyr::crossing(df, dates)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   d     t     dates     
#  <fct> <fct> <date>    
#1 d1    t1    2016-05-01
#2 d1    t1    2016-06-01
#3 d1    t1    2016-07-01
#4 d2    t2    2016-05-01
#5 d2    t2    2016-06-01
#6 d2    t2    2016-07-01
```

Comment: I prefer your answer but  the other answers also seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::expand_grid()`:

```
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(df, dates)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  d     t     dates     
  <fct> <fct> <date>    
1 d1    t1    2016-05-01
2 d1    t1    2016-06-01
3 d1    t1    2016-07-01
4 d2    t2    2016-05-01
5 d2    t2    2016-06-01
6 d2    t2    2016-07-01
```

Comment: Is that a newer version of tidyr as I get: Error: 'expand.grid' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood your intention but in your example, `merge` does the job:

```r
merge(df, dates)
   d  t          y
1 d1 t1 2016-05-01
2 d2 t2 2016-05-01
3 d1 t1 2016-06-01
4 d2 t2 2016-06-01
5 d1 t1 2016-07-01
6 d2 t2 2016-07-01
```

From the doc:

> If by or both by.x and by.y are of length 0 (a length zero vector or NULL), the result, r, is the Cartesian product of x and y, i.e., dim(r) = c(nrow(x)*nrow(y), ncol(x) + ncol(y)).

Rows are not ordered (you can do it in a second step) but the result is the same.

Comment: It appears to work. Sorry I prefer crossing, which is more natural for me with sql background.

Comment: Ok, no problem, that's a question of preference